# Apply style onMouseEnter on mapped element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to apply a custom style when I hover a div.
I have a `.map()` function that will create a card for each element in the datas received.

To achieve that :

- I map my datas and give them a unique index as `key`
- I use `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` to add and remove my class

I know I could use `:hover` in CSS, but as a React / Tailwind project, I try to write as less `css` as I can, and I want to learn by trying new stuff.

**Problem**
When I hover my card, the current card and all the next ones until the last one take that class. not only the hovered one.

I don't understand why it takes all last card after hovered one.

Where is my mistake ?

**Here is what I tried**

```
const addCustomShadow = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => {
    const card = e.currentTarget;
    card.classList.add("custom-box-shadow");
};

const removeCustomShadow = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => {
    const card = e.currentTarget;
    card.classList.remove("custom-box-shadow");
};

{data.map((project, index) => {
   return (
      <div
          key={index}
          onMouseEnter={addCustomShadow}
          onMouseLeave={removeCustomShadow}
          className='rounded-lg bg-white p-6 shadow-xl transition-all duration-150'>
             [...]
      </div>
    );
})}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a useState variable and maintain the state for each item in the map

```
const [showClass, setShowClass] = useState({})
const addCustomShadow = (id: number) => {
    setShowClass(state => ({
          ...state,
         [id] : true
    }))
};

const removeCustomShadow = (id: number) => {
    setShowClass(state => ({
          ...state,
         [id] : false
    }))
};

{data.map((project, index) => {
   return (
      <div
          key={index}
          onMouseEnter={() => addCustomShadow(project.id)}
          onMouseLeave={() => removeCustomShadow(project.id)}
          className={`rounded-lg bg-white p-6 shadow-xl transition-all duration-150 ${showClass[project.id]? 'custom-box-shadow': ''}`}>
             [...]
      </div>
    );
})}
```